# What does this sentence mean in flannery o' connor's short story?

Tags: american-english, tenses, books

I was reading '*A good man is hard to find*'
and I could not understand this:

> It isn't a soul in this green world of God's that you can trust", She said. "**And I don't count nobody out of that, not nobody**,"

[Google Books - Page 38](https://books.google.fr/books?id=hx_67tvCQK8C&pg=PA38&dq=and%20I%20don't%20count%20nobody%20out%20of%20that%20a%20good%20man%20is%20hard&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvrfXljafNAhUJ0hoKHX2sB_4Q6AEIHzAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Can you add more surrounding context please, eg the entire passage or paragraph?

Comment: What specifically do you not understand?  The use of "don't count nobody" -- a double negative -- tags the speaker as speaking a rural/illiterate dialect.  The "not nobody" (again, a double negative), is, of course, just for emphasis.

Comment: This specific [fictional] conversation is analysed [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ysWgBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA59&dq=%22a+soul+in+this+green+world+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22a%20soul%20in%20this%20green%20world%20of%22&f=false). But the ELU question itself is Off Topic because there's no evidence of prior research, and we've no idea exactly what aspect of the text OP doesn't understand.

Answer (score 7):

This is a use of **[double negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negative)**. Here, it seems like it is just used to emphasize the point. The sentence, with proper grammar, would thus be:

> And I don't count **anybody** out of that, not **anybody**.

Which means that there is no exception to the first statement: you can trust no one, with no exception to the rule.

You can find more Double negative uses in literature here: http://grammar.about.com/od/d/g/doubnegterm.htm

Please note that double negative **can** be grammatically correct to use to form a positive argument (in which case they cancel each other out). For example:

> I **couldn’t** **not** help him.

i.e. *I couldn't stand by without helping him.*

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @madward's answer. Another phrasing could be  ....

> [...]"And I don't count nobody out of that, not nobody,"

==>

> [...] "**and, I emphasise, there are no exceptions,**"